# Merging multiple rows as separate columns using keys from second table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

**Users:**

```
int player_id
varchar player_name
```

**Games:**

```
int game_id
int player_id1
int player_id2
```

I want to make a query that takes in a player id as a parameter, and returns info on each game, along with the player's name.  So far, what I have is the following:

```
SELECT 
    game_id, 
    player_id1, 
    player_id2, 
from GAMES, GAME_STATES 
where player_id1=@playerid or player_id2=@playerid
```

The part I'm stuck at is a simple way to have it return the names of players along with the player ids.  The returning query would have 5 columns, one of the game id, two for each player id, and two for each of their names.

One solution I thought of is:

```
SELECT 
  game_id, 
  player_id1, 
  (select player_name from USERS where player_id=player_id1) as player_name1, player_id2, 
  (select player_name from USERS where player_id=player_id2) as player_name2, 
from GAMES, GAME_STATES 
where player_id1=@playerid or player_id2=@playerid
```

However, this seems like a lot of extra work on the database since there would be 2 more queries per row returned.  If I have to do that, I'm wondering if making requests for names as a second query on the client side is a better option?  Then the client could create a list of unique ids, and do one query for all of them.  I'm not too worried about latency since the client and server are in the same data center.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I believe a Join is in order, for those who know how to explain it better than I?

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT game_id, u1.player_name, u2.player_name FROM games AS game INNER JOIN users AS u1 ON y1.playerid = game.player_id1 INNER JOIN users AS u2 ON u2.playedid = game.player_id2 WHERE player_id1 = @playerid OR player_id2 = @playerid`

Should do the trick